# WCF - There was an error downloading

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a test class that I'm using trying to make a WCF service, the class looks like this:

```
public class TestObject
{

    public int ObjID { get; set; }


    public string ObjName { get; set; }

    public TestObject(int id, string name) {
        ObjID = id;
        ObjName = name;
    }
}
```

When I try to import the service reference into a clien app, I get this error `There was an error downloading [...]` . If I add `[DataContract]` and `[DataMember]` tags to my class, it works just fine, however, I would like to use it without adding DataContract.

Any idea about solving this issue?

Comment: Yes. Use [DataContract] as per WCF guidelines...

Comment: Isn't there a way to make it work without using [DataContract] ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to use wcf object without specifiing the `[DataContract]` or `[DataMember]` attribute, but in order for that to work you need to also include an empty contructor.  This constructor does not have to be public as in the example below, but you do have to have one (public, private, internal, etc)

```
public class TestObject
{
    public int ObjID { get; set; }
    public string ObjName { get; set; }

    public TestObject() 
    { 
    }

    public TestObject(int id, string name) 
    {
        ObjID = id;
        ObjName = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you please tell me what's the logic behind this? And what if the class already has a constructor without parameters?

Comment: Can I tell you why Microsoft decided to design it this way?  Nope.  Not sure what your getting on on the second question.

Comment: This is not reliable, some version of the .net framework do not support this. If your server is windows server 2008, there is a chance that you will only get empty object.

Answer (score 0):

You resolve the issue by adding [DataContract] and [DataMember]. WCF needs these tags for serialization of your data objects. Without them, the object or field will not be serialized or included in the contract.

Answer (score 0):

```
[Serializable]
```

Try that attribute on the class .. as a first attempt.

See:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733127.aspx

Here is the article I was looking for (or one like the one I remember)

http://www.biztalkgurus.com/biztalk_server/biztalk_blogs/b/biztalksyn/archive/2008/05/13/datacontracts-without-attributes-poco-support-in-net-3-5-sp1.aspx

Things changed with Framework 3.5 SP1.

So, the answer is "Yes you can".. "but it depends on the Framework Version" and it depends on the Serialize (DataContractSerializer).

Comment: I read some articles saying that it's not mandatory to use [DataContract]. Like this one: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/a184b637-62d4-49c6-a30b-3137d780d1b2/datacontract-in-wcf?forum=wcf

Comment: That's why I said "try serializable" as a first attempt.

Comment: @gabitzish I have seen it working without the tags, however when deployed on a production server it stopped working. Just include them as microsoft recommends.

Comment: Isn't @iamkrillin's solution going to work on a production server? I've added an empty constructor, and it seems to work fine :)

Comment: WCF is a huge beast...and there are simple and then there are complex parts of it.  "TypeSharing" vs "DataSharing" is one of them.  So if you found something that works in your scenario, roll with it.  But be careful of blanket-statements.  Yes, he is correct, I missed the empty constructor issue, even though I've encountered that before.